# activity!! showing underlined in red color when updated android studio to 4.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

After updating android studio 4.1 using activity!! is showing as error underlined red and when i run the app it runs fine. Also it is forcing to replace with requireActivity(). Why is it happening. Is it some wrong with the kotlin version chang or something. I want to stick on to the activty!! and not to requireActivity() as it produces some illegal state exception. And my project is a very big project so my team not allowing to use requireActivity() method.
What needed to be changed to use activity!! without error as before?
Your help is appreciated

Comment: you understand that using activity!! is also going to cause you crashes and errors, right ?

Comment: *I want to stick on to the activty!! and not to requireActivity() as it produces some illegal state exception* well, if requireActivity() would produce illegal state then activity!! would throw KotlinNullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

It's an Android Lint error.

If you really want to, you can suppress it with

```
@SuppressLint("UseRequireInsteadOfGet")
```

However, from fragment lifecycle point of view you will get runtime exceptions using either `activity!!` or `requireActivity()`. Either Kotlin null pointer exception or illegal state exception.

I would just do as the error suggests and use `requireActivity()` in your fragment wherever you expect to have a nonnull activity. The exception messages and intent of the code is more clear with `requireActivity()`. I consider `!!` a code smell that is usually best avoided.